# Android/Java check car plate number for invalid characters

Tags: java, android, regex

My question is about checking string for invalid characters, and if they containt replace them.

As example i have string SK5IU0K, which have to divided into to(maybe)  two strings. So we have SK5I and U0K.

In this example I would like to check if second part contain "0" and replace it with "O". And in the first part check if it contain I  replace it with "1".

I know somehow regex have to be used, but I do not really can imagine currently how to make it work.

This check is for UK car plate numbers which have to followed sertain rule.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_the_United_Kingdom,_Crown_dependencies_and_overseas_territories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vin = vin.substring(0, 4).replaceAll("I", "1") + vin.substring(4).replaceAll("0", "O");
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [String.replace(char oldChar,char newChar)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))

```
public static String validateCarPlate(String plate) {
    return plate.replace('0', 'O').replace('I', '1');
}
```